# How to append RTK Query response with previously cached data

Tags: typescript, react-native, infinite-scroll, rtk-query, flatlist

Using a RTK query, I'm attempting to add infinite scrolling to a Flatlist. How do I integrate the new response with the data that was previously fetched? I must also replace the existing data with the new response upon refetch.

const {data} = usePostQuery();

Is it possible to get the value of data as a combined result of current data with the previous data.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer for this [SO question][1]: 


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909356/is-there-any-way-to-fetch-all-the-responses-stored-in-api-slice-rtk-query

Answer (score 0):

The solution I believe you're looking for involves [merge](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#merge) and [serializeQueryArgs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs). I found that out from [this](https://rohitbels.medium.com/pagination-infinite-loading-with-redux-toolkit-createapi-a265ac25c3bd) medium article.